# Magento 2: Can't Install Sample Data, Before Install Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to install Magento 2 Merchant Beta with Sample Data on a Windows 7 machine, using Xampp. I'm trying to install Sample Data during the Magento Install Wizard.

Problem is, sample data check box is disabled.

I've already did the procedure as mentioned from [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html).

Here's what I did:

1. I've installed the latest version of Xampp (PHP 5.5.28)
2. Installed Composer for Windows, with context menus enabled.
3. Created a magento2 folder inside htdocs of Xampp.
4. Copied Magento 2 files to `magento2` folder. Files was downloaded from `https://github.com/magento/magento2`.
5. Installed composer in `magento2` folder using the context menu.
6. I've edited composer.json and changed the line with `alpha` with `beta`. That is:

   ```
   "minimum-stability": "beta"
   ```
7. Then I invoked the command (then waited for few minutes):

   ```
   composer require magento/sample-data:1.0.0-beta
   ```
8. After that, I started to install Magento using the webui.
9. My problem is the `SAMPLE DATA` part, it is disabled and grayed out.

What could be the problem? Or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue and here is solution for this :)

add - "minimum-stability": "beta"    to composer.json

modified json should look like this :

"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "Magento project (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "version": "1.0.0-beta",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],

then invoke commands :

composer config repositories.magento composer http://packages.magento.com

composer require magento/sample-data:1.0.0-beta

Now important one :

composer update

last one is :  remove cache and page cache     i.e under var folder

Now reload magento setup page you will have check-box available to install sample data.

Answer (score 0):

To install sample data using the command line, enter the following command as the file system owner in the <magento_root> folder:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

If you’re installing sample data after installing Magento, you must also run the following command to update the database and schema in the <magento_root> folder:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The following authentication error might display:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

If the error displays, change to your Magento installation directory and run composer update, which will prompt you for your authentication keys.

After you download the sample data packages, log in to your Magento server as, or switch to, the file system owner and enter the following command in <magento_root> folder:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

for more details check below link:

[install sample data](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html)